# Symfony unitOfWork

Tags: php, symfony, unit-of-work

I have a little problem to solve.

I have two entities with a many to many relation (something like posts and tags)
I want to have a event that is called onFlush on post entity.
The case is that on this event I must have the changes that are made on a collection od tags to that post and the base collection before the changes are made.
The first part i know how to make by getScheduledCollectionUpdates but how to get the base collection of the entity that will be updated?

Im using symfony 4.4 and doctrine

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Doctrine Lifecycle Event Subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-subscribers).

You can perform an action the moment before data is written to the database via the `preUpdate` method. It also gives you access to `PreUpdateEventArgs` where you can get/modify the data and do what you need.

Create a folder `src/EventSubscriber` then add this file.

**Example**

```
// src/EventSubscriber/YourEntityNameSubscriber.php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\EventSubscriber\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;

class YourEntityNameSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return array(
            Events::preUpdate,
        );
    }

    /**
     * On YourEntityName update.
     *
     * @param PreUpdateEventArgs $args
     * @return void
     */
    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if ($entity instanceof YourEntityName) {
            // Do whatever you need to do here on this specific entity..

            // Example access tags $entity->getTags();
            // You can use $args->hasChangedField('fieldname');
            // Get data $args->getNewValue('fieldname')
            // Also can change data by using $args->setNewValue('fieldname', null);
        }
    }
}
```